# jQueryで特定のクラスが付与されていたら、アニメーションを実行するには？

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQueryで、特定のクラス（以下.animate）が付与されていたら、その中の特定のクラス（.slideFirst）を探してアニメーションを実行させたいのですが、うまくいきません。
.animateのクラスは、最初から付与されているものではなく、スライドが一番前に来た時に、付与されるものです。以下、jsの一番最後に入れたのですが、動きません。

//上部省略

```
if (index === 0) {
      current.$node.addClass('animate');
```

//上部、animateクラスを付与した後に、アニメーション実行を入れたいのですが、動きません。

```
$(function(){
    $('.animate').find('.slideFirst').stop().animate({left: '-500px', display: 'none'}, {'duration':500,'easing':'linear'});
});
```

Comment: `.animate`クラスを付与するタイミングで`.slideFirst`に対して`animate()`を呼び出すのではダメなのですか？

Comment: display: none はアニメーションできないと思います。徐々に消えていくアニメーションであれば、opacity（不透明度）を使います。

Answer (score 1):

下記のどちらかで動くようになると思います。
・`slideFirst`を設定している要素に`position`を追加する
・`left`の代わりに`marginLeft`を使用する

また、mok2pokさんがコメントに記載しているように、要素を消したいのであれば`opacity`を使用すればいけると思います。

サンプル
http://codepen.io/negibouze/pen/xGqdyq

```js
$(function() {
  var $wrapper = $('.wrapper');
  var idList = [
    '#n1', '#n5', '#n4', '#n3', '#n2'
  ];
  var indexArray = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0];
  var attrIndex = 0;
  var attrList = [{
      bottom: 0,
      'z-index': 10,
      opacity: 1
    },
    {
      bottom: '18%',
      'z-index': 9,
      opacity: 1
    },
    {
      bottom: '30%',
      'z-index': 8,
      opacity: 0.9
    },
    {
      bottom: '40%',
      'z-index': 7,
      opacity: 0.7
    },
    {
      bottom: '50%',
      'z-index': 6,
      //opacity: 0.4
    }
  ];
  var childAttrList = [{
      width: '100%'
    },
    {
      width: '83%'
    },
    {
      width: '73%'
    },
    {
      width: '63%'
    },
    {
      width: '53%'
    }
  ];

  // webkitAnimationEndを使用
  var move = function() {
    var aIndex = attrIndex;
    attrIndex = (attrIndex === idList.length - 1) ? 0 : attrIndex + 1;
    var nodes = idList.map(function(id) {
      return {
        $node: $wrapper.find(id)
      };
    });
    nodes.forEach(function(current, currentIndex, whole) {
      var index = indexArray[aIndex];
      // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
      if (index === 4) current.$node.css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      $('img', current.$node).animate(childAttrList[index], 1000);
      current.$node.animate(attrList[index], 1000, function() {
        // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
        if (index === 4) current.$node.animate({
          opacity: 0.4
        }, 500);
        current.$node.removeClass('animate');
        if (index === 0) {
          animate(current.$node);
        }
      });
      aIndex = (aIndex === whole.length - 1) ? 0 : aIndex + 1;
    });
  }
  var animate = function(obj) {
    obj.one('animationend webkitAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd', function() {
      move();
    });
    obj.addClass('animate');
    // position
    $('.animate').find('.set-position').stop().animate({
      left: '-150px',
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      'duration': 1000,
      'easing': 'linear',
      complete: function() {
        $(this).animate({
          left: '0px',
          opacity: 1.0
        }, 1500);
      }
    });
    // marginLeft
    $('.animate').find('.margin_left').stop().animate({
      marginLeft: '-150px',
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      'duration': 1500,
      'easing': 'linear',
      complete: function() {
        $(this).animate({
          marginLeft: '0px',
          opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }
  // 最初の1回を実行
  animate($('#n1'));
  /*  
      // setIntervalを使用
      var move = function(isFirst) {
      var aIndex = attrIndex;
      attrIndex = (attrIndex === idList.length - 1) ? 0 : attrIndex + 1;
      var nodes = idList.map(function(id) {
        return {
          $node: $wrapper.find(id)
        };
      });
      nodes.forEach(function(current, currentIndex, whole) {
        var index = indexArray[aIndex];
        // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
        if (!isFirst && index === 4) current.$node.css({opacity:0});
        $('img', current.$node).animate(childAttrList[index], 1000);
        current.$node.animate(attrList[index], 1000, function() {
          // 移動中は見えなくする場合はこの辺で調整する
          if (!isFirst && index === 4) current.$node.animate({opacity:0.4}, 500);
          current.$node.removeClass('animate');
          if (index === 0) {
            current.$node.addClass('animate');
          }
        });
        aIndex = (aIndex === whole.length - 1) ? 0 : aIndex + 1;
      });
    }
    // 待ち時間が長いので最初の1回を実行
    move(true);
    setInterval(function() { move(false) }, 5100);
  */
});
```

```css
.set-position {
  position: relative;
}

#slide {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#slide ul {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

#slide li {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}

#slide #n1 {
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
}

#slide #n1 img {
  width: 100%;
}

#slide #n2 {
  bottom: 18%;
  z-index: 9;
  opacity: 1;
}

#slide #n2 img {
  width: 83%;
}

#slide #n3 {
  bottom: 30%;
  z-index: 8;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#slide #n3 img {
  width: 73%;
}

#slide #n4 {
  bottom: 40%;
  z-index: 7;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#slide #n4 img {
  width: 63%;
}

#slide #n5 {
  bottom: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

#slide #n5 img {
  width: 53%;
}

img {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
}


/* 3秒止めてから2秒かけてscaleoutのkeyframesを実行（足して5秒）。jsの5秒と同じ。 */

.animate {
  -webkit-animation: scaleout 2s ease-in-out 3s;
  animation: scaleout 2s ease-in-out 3s;
}


/* n1を1.5倍に拡大して消す */

@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scaleout {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="slide">
  <ul class="wrapper">
    <li id="n1"><img src="" alt="イメージ1" />
      <div class="set-position">positionを設定</div>
      <div class="margin_left">marginLeftを使用</div>
    </li>
    <li id="n2"><img src="" alt="イメージ2" />
      <div class="set-position">positionを設定</div>
      <div class="margin_left">marginLeftを使用</div>
    </li>
    <li id="n3"><img src="" alt="イメージ3" />
      <div class="set-position">positionを設定</div>
      <div class="margin_left">marginLeftを使用</div>
    </li>
    <li id="n4"><img src="" alt="イメージ4" />
      <div class="set-position">positionを設定</div>
      <div class="margin_left">marginLeftを使用</div>
    </li>
    <li id="n5"><img src="" alt="イメージ5" />
      <div class="set-position">positionを設定</div>
      <div class="margin_left">marginLeftを使用</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

参考
[jQuery animate({left:“+=10”}) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723230/jquery-animateleft-10-not-working)

Comment: ita_3yさま、可愛い猫のサンプルありがとうございます。ｊQueryのanimate関数ではキャメルケースでmarginLeftと書くのですね。cssでpositionの設定を適用したら、できました！opacityは徐々に消えていくではなく、スッとすぐに消したいので、別で設定しようかと思いました。cssは噂のsassでしょうか。こちらも勉強になりました。今後使えるようにじっくり理解していきたいと思います。ありがとうございました。m(_ _)m